# HTML5 Best way to define coordinates for parts of an image, that when someone clicks on that we can find which part clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to HTML5 and i have working on converting simple flash game to HTML5. What i have to do is, i am having an image of a character, so i have define the parts of the image in such a way that when user clicks on the head it should say you have clicked on head, and if some one click e.g on hand it should say you have clicked on hand or it is clicked in the face of the character.

I have done googling and find we can define different shapes and i have drawn and got successfull[image: Image i have used]

So i just want to know that in my image what should i have to do, i have to use images for different parts or i have to draw character using HTML5 **bezierCurveTo** function.

Please tell me the best way and how can i do that.

Thanks

Comment: You can use SVG for this and use a JS library like Raphael or D3

Comment: Here is an example. http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5728198/WorldMap/world.htm and here is the source http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/262179/SVG-World-Map

Answer (score 2):

You can do it either with Images, SVG Elements, or Canvas.

If you have Images or SVG Elements, you can hook the `onclick` event of the Image to tell when it is clicked.  Images will be the rectangular bounding box of the image, but SVG Elements will be the tight bounds.  Use `document.getElementById(<id>)` to get the element from your page.

If you are using Canvas, you can use also use `onclick` but inside the callback, you can use [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.isPointInPath()`](http://www.javascripture.com/CanvasRenderingContext2D#isPointInPath) to see if the point is in the head.  This will allow you to check the exact bounds of the head, not just the rectangle around the head.

```
canvas.onclick = function(event) {
  context.beginPath(); 
  // Recreate the head path here. 

  if (context.isPointInPath(event.offsetX, event.offsetY)) {
    // Click was within the head
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @nkron for your answer, acctually the thing is that in the image i have given if you see the hairs of the image are coming below the face also and that is not a rectangular or circular shape, so what i have to do if someone click on the hairs part it should say you have clicked in hairs, if someone has clicked out of that are that should not say anything

Comment: Yes, SVG allows you to do that. The images are not made of pixels puth paths. Thats why the name SVG. Scalable Vector Graphics...

Comment: Thanks @MarsOne thanks for your help i think the above example link provided by you would work, thanks thanks allot..

Comment: Are you using SVG Dinesh?  I've updated my answer with some details to point out that you can use onclick with SVG elements of any shape, not just rectangles.  If you are using Canvas, the isPointInPath method will also work on any shape.  You must define the path using path methods such as bezierPointTo() before calling isPointInPath().